# Preventing modification of returned lists in python

Tags: python, list

I'm working om my python skills and am trying out creating some classes. Since python is reference based any list returned by a class method can be modified by the caller which would then reflect back in the class (as I have it). What would be the correct way of avoiding this? I was thinking either converting the nested list to nested tuples or doing a deep copy?

Comment: I think you are correct. Either return a tuple or return a copy of the list

Comment: Depends on the use case.  The specific implementation determines whether a mutable copy or an immutable original is the better way to go.  There are also more advanced mechanisms that would allow you to create a read-only interface on top of a mutable list.

Comment: I usually find it sufficient to have no safeguards, and just warn clients in the documentation not to modify the data. Then again, I am usually my own client, and I can trust myself to not do anything dumb (most of the time). If you're writing an interface that will be used by other people, I can see why you would want a more serious deterrent.

Comment: @Kevin: I never trust myself not to do anything dumb. Thatwould be inappropriate obtimism, and thus dumb by itself. I know myself... :->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning tuples is a fairly standard way to give back immutable lists.  Another option would be to return an immutable "view" of the list.  I don't think the stdlib currently contains such a class, so you'd probably have to roll your own, but it would be fairly straight forward.  Basically, the class would contain a single private instance variable (the underlying list); and would implement only the read operations (`__getitem__`, `__len__`, etc) and would delegate them to the instance variable (wrapping any child items in "view" objects as necessary).

Comment: You'd have to go a bit more complex than that.  Your list wrapper would have to return read-only versions of its children, otherwise only the top level of the list would be immutable.  You could also wrap the whole thing in a descriptor so that the difference between the internal and external interfaces to the list were hidden from the user, to make a bit cleaner of a user experience.

Comment: Also, rather than trying to implement all the read methods on the wrapper, it might be easier to subclass `list` directly and just override the write methods to raise an exception.

Comment: @sr2222: Subclassing list is not useful if you want a "view" object -- list owns its own data.  Presumably the OP still wants to be able to modify the list within the class.  (If not, then they should definitely just be using tuples.)

Comment: Ultimately, you are trying to make something that implements a modified version of the list interface.  Whether you build that up from scratch by subclassing `object` or start from `list` and modify only what needs changing, ultimately, you get to the same point.  However, `isinstance(immutable_list, list) == True` is the intuitive situation here.  That said, you would have to modify all the read methods anyway, since you'd need them all to return immutable versions of the children.